# Query results not showing records with null values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm designing a search form to search my access database based on 4 text fields, Firstname, Surname, Phonenumber and Promo Code.

The queries look like:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![txtFirstName] & "*"
Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![txtSurnameName] & "*"
Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![txtPhone] & "*"
Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![txtPromo] & "*"
```

The search should return all records if all the fields are blank. When you enter some values in the text boxes, the results are narrowed down to matches.

It almost works fine, but problems occur when there is no value in certain fields. For instance, if someone doesn't have a promo code then their record will always be skipped over even if you leave it blank. I assume the access query doesn't like blank fields.

What's the easiest way to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the text boxes may be a bit of a distraction here, because the issue is more basic.  Consider this query ...

```sql
SELECT f.id, f.some_text
FROM tblFoo AS f
WHERE f.some_text Like "*";
```

It returns rows where `some_text` contains *any* non-Null value, even an empty string.  However it will not return rows where `some_text` is Null.

The reason is that Null in a `Like` comparison will never evaluate as True.  Consider this example from the Immediate window ...

```vb
? "foo" Like "*"
True
? Null Like "*"
Null
```

For your `Like` comparisons, I think you want the rows where the target field contains the text box text.  But return all rows when the text box is Null.  You can do that by combining those two conditions with `OR`.

```sql
WHERE
    [Promo Code] Like "*" & Forms!SearchF!txtPromo & "*"
    OR
    Forms!SearchF!txtPromo Is Null
```

When the text box is Null, the second part of the `OR` is true for all rows, so all rows are returned.

When the text box is not Null, only those rows which satisfy the `Like` comparison are returned.