# Show all entries (including null) unless criteria is met

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a table on a form that should show all entries from a table.  This table can be filtered by two fields on the form which modifies the query.  The problem is that entries where one field is null do not show up.  I added the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147090/query-results-not-showing-records-with-null-values) and it worked (or so I thought) but now the first query does not work.

The queries I was using are

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Tooling]![SearchToolNumber] & "*"
```

and

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Tooling]![SearchToolName] & "*"
```

The only field that can have null values is the ToolName field but adding

```
Or Forms!Tooling!SearchToolName Is Null
```

allows it to return results with a null ToolName but now the ToolNumber query does not work.

How can I have it return everything if both fields are left blank but still have each field work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well adding

```
Or Forms!Tooling!SearchToolNumber Is Null
```

to the first query solved the problem and now both fields work as expected as well as returning nulls from the table.